# java.sql.SQLException: Can't find type 'TIMESTAMP' when saving Spark dataframe to Sybase

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, sybase

I'm using spark in the java application and I have to save a dataframe to an existing db table. Database is a Sybase. Spark version 3.0.1. I have several fields of type Timestamp in the dataframe. So looks like they cannot be mapped to database fileds of type 'datetime' but why not? I'm using this statement trying to insert dataframe:

```
outputDS.write().mode(SaveMode.Append).jdbc(URL, tableName, properties);
```

Also there are statement example how I'm creating timestamp columns in the output dataset:

```
.withColumn("DateCreated", lit(new TimeStamp(System.currentTimeMillis())).cast(DataTypes.TimestampType))
```

Here are schemas:

**dataframe schema:**

```
rDay: timestamp
rName: string
rValue: double
rId: integer
rCountry: string
rRegion: string 
rCustomerId: string 
rLevel: string 
rUserCreated: string
rUserUpdated: string
rDateCreated: timestamp 
rDateUpdated: timestamp
```

**db table schema:**

```
rId                bigint
rCustomerId        bigint 
rCountry           varchar(50)
rRegion            varchar(15)
rName              varchar(50)
rValue             decimal(8,4)
rLevel             varchar(30)
rDay               datetime
rUserCreated       varchar(15)
rDateCreated       datetime 
rUserUpdated       varchar(15)
rDateUpdated       datetime
```

So, as I understood to insert rows from spark dataframe to existing db table their schemas must be equal. But trying to achieve this I'm getting this exception:

> java.sql.SQLException: Can't find type 'TIMESTAMP'

And when I try to change Timestamp type of my fields to for example DateType, I get another exception like " already has an object 'tableName' in the database", so I guess it's because schemas don't match this time. So, is there a way to do it somehow? Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you please update the question with the dataframe schema and table schema?

Comment: Ok, I just added. Not able to copy from the source, so it's approximate schema, with actual types

Comment: As you have datetime column in the target database you should change the data types of the column that you have in dataframe with timestamp to datetime. you should also make sure that the order of the columns should be same. Long back I had similar issue in SQL and I resolved that in this manner

Comment: But there's no such a type DateTime in spark DateTypes, just Date, which is not appropriate, cause I also need time. And as I read spark Timestamp should be mapped to database datetime as well as java.sql.Timestamp mapped to db datetime. But I didn't think of an order, maybe that's a clue, thanks

Comment: In that case make sure you convert your timestamp column in dataframe to the format that target database use for datetime as different format can also lead to errors.

Comment: So, I've changed dataframe to make it ordered, and made sure the schema is equal to db table schema, but still have this 'Can't find type 'TIMESTAMP'' exception. Looks like spark and sybase timestamp/datetime types can't be mapped to each other or I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to cast again to `DataTypes.TimestampType` as the :

```
.withColumn("DateCreated", lit(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis())))
```

already gives column `DateCreated` of type `timestamp`.

Also, you should use Spark builtin function [`current_timestamp`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#current_timestamp--) for that:

```
.withColumn("DateCreated", current_timestamp())
```

> I'm getting this exception java.sql.SQLException: Can't find type 'TIMESTAMP'

I don't know much about Sybase, but you can try to stringify timestamp columns before you write into table:

```
.withColumn("DateCreated", date_format(current_timestamp(), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))
```

Comment: So, just tried like this, and now spark saves these fields as strings. So it doesn't match db 'datetime' type and I get 'java.sql.Exception: There is already an object named 'tableName' in the database'

Comment: @sergio1399 What is the connector you're using to write from spark to Sybase?

Comment: Actually I totally forgot about the driver. I've added this .option("driver", driverClassName) to the writing statement and it helps. Thank you very much! At least I sorted out this issue. But now I have java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ASE has out of LOCKS... I think it's more about server configuration.